# How to extract the dictionary if element in list matches

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of dictionary

- I need to check first if email_id is exist in the dictionary
- if exist then return that particular dictionary
- If email_id doesn't exist then only check the `group` list

```
test =  [
    {
      "email": "groups@gmail.com",
      "type": "Group"
    },
    {
      "email": "user@gmail.com",
      "type": "Single"
    }
  ]
```

Code is below

```
group = ['groups2@gmail.com', 'groups1@gmail.com', 'groups@gmail.com']


email_id = "user@gmail.com"


def teat():
    for each in test:
        if email_id == each['email']:
            return (each)
        else:
            for ad_group in group:
                if ad_group == each['email'] :
                    return (each)
teat()
```

My output is
`{'email': 'groups@gmail.com', 'type': 'Group'}`

but expected is
`{'email': 'user@gmail.com', 'type': 'Single'}`

Comment: In the `test` dictionary `{'email': 'groups@gmail.com', 'type': 'Group'}` placed before `{'email': 'user@gmail.com', 'type': 'Single'}`. So, in the first iteration of function the `if` condition isn't true and in the `else` you reach to `{'email': 'groups@gmail.com', 'type': 'Group'}` output.

Comment: that  i got it, how to implement in code,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the first condition requires an exhaustive search of the whole list, you really need two loops. One to check the first condition and one for the second.

```
def teat():
    for each in test:
        if email_id == each['email']:
            return each
    for each in test:
        if each['email'] in group:
            return each
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run both for loops separately. In your current code your start searching for a group match as soon as your first email doesn't match.

```
def teat():
     for each in test:
         if email_id == each['email']:
             return (each)

     for each in test:
         for ad_group in group:
             if ad_group == each['email'] :
                 return (each)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to iterate the same list twice, use this method:

```
def teat():
    email_match = None
    group_match = None
    for each in test:
        if email_id == each['email']:
            email_match = each
            break
        for ad_group in group:
            if ad_group == each['email']:
                group_match = each
    return email_match or group_match
```

Comment: Also note, that if this method matches on condition 2 for multiple entities, it will return the last value instead of the first.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible within the specs of the question. I was going to suggest you to convert `groups` to a set for faster lookup in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, that could be a good optimization if the size of `group` is large. I prefer using more basic structures if there isn't a big performance gain. Generally this helps me when reading my own code like "I'm not using just a basic list so there's something clever about this" :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, both if and else are returning something which means it is not iterating through the whole list.

I have modified your code a bit.

```
def teat():
    for each in test:
        if email_id == each['email']:
            mydict = each
            return mydict
        else:
            for ad_group in group:
                if ad_group == each['email'] :
                    mydict = each
    return mydict
```

**Output:**

```
{'email': 'user@gmail.com', 'type': 'Single'}
```

Comment: If no match is found this will raise an `UnboundLocalError`. Also it keeps iterating even after a match is found.

Comment: Thanks for identifying this @Selcuk. I have updated my code to return the dict as soon as the match is found.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct to say that what you essentially want to return is the last matching dictionary in the list (at least, the preferred answer does seem to do that)?
If that is the case, why not processing the list starting from the end and returning the first element which satifies one of the 2 conditions?

```
def teat():
    for i in range(len(test) - 1, -1, -1):
        each = test[i]
        if email_id == each['email'] or each['email'] in group:
            return each
```